# PgAdmin running in Docker can't connect to Postgres server

Tags: docker, pgadmin

I have `pgadmin` running in a **Docker container** (available in my browser at http://localhost:8080)
Postgres is installed in my system (not Dockerized), and I have no problem connecting to it using:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://bob:1234@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres')
engine.connect()
```

The problem is, when I create a server in pgadmin, and try to connect to **host name/address** 127.0.0.1, **port** 5432, **Maintenance database** postgres, **user** bob, and **password** 1234, I get:

```
Unable to connect to server: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed Connection refused. Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Comment: `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`) in a container means "inside this container". Postgres isn't running inside the pgadmin container, it's running somewhere else. You need to use an ip address that maps to your host (or put postgres in a container).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the container how to connect to the host. There's a special host name called `host-gateway` that maps to the host. The convention is to create a name called `host.docker.internal` that maps to the host.

You do that by adding `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to your `docker run` command so it becomes something like

```
docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway <other options> pgadmin
```

Then you can reach postgres by using `host.docker.internal` as the postgres hostname instead of `127.0.0.1` in pgadmin.